# How to use marionette nested layouts views?

Tags: javascript, marionette

Suppose I have this page, I want the content of child view be correctly inserted to ParentLayoutView.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>test marionette</title>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/backbone.wreqr/lib/backbone.wreqr.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/marionette/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="layout_container">
        Parent content
        <div id="child">initial content of child</div>
    </div>
<script>

    'use strict';

    window.alert("Start the application!");

    var App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    App.addRegions({
        mainRegion: "#layout_container"
    });

    var ParentLayoutView =  Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
        template: '<div class="this is a parent template">Parent content after show()</div>',
        regions:  {
            childRegion:     {
                el: "#child"
            }
            //childRegion: "#child" //BTW, this is does not work, it throws "#child not in DOM" error
        },

        onBeforeShow: function () {
            this.showChildView('childRegion', new childView());
        },
        onShow: function () {
            window.alert("Now child template is replaced by parent without attached child");
        }
    });

    var childView =  Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: '<div class="this is a CHILD template">Child class content after show()</div>',
        onShow: function () {
            window.alert("We showed child view!");
        }
    });

    App.on('start', function () {

        var layout = new ParentLayoutView();
        App.mainRegion.show(layout);
    });

    App.start();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But instead I get that after child view is rendered and inserted to DOM (why?), a ParentLayoutView then totally replace it, so I see only parent content. I wish to see Child content inside Parent, like any server side template engine do. And I think all job must be done virtually in memory and only one root node at #layout_container must be inserted at the end of process. So all nested children must be rendered and attached to each other and only the most parent view must be inserted in DOM. I read this http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.layoutview.html#efficient-nested-view-structures

Answer (score 0):

When you show the layout view in `mainRegion`, you replace the current contents of that element. So your `#child` div disappears and the content of `#layout_container` becomes what's in your `ParentLayoutView` template. But that template doesn't have a `#child` element, so the region is invalid and there's no place to put the child view.

Instead, make sure the template for `ParentLayoutView` contains the full HTML for that element, including the `#child` div.

Comment: after parent region show() all child are replaced anyway. And second problem - I want to avoid any DOM manipulations, i do not want child to be shown before parent. I want a single operation with DOM - inserting only one time.

Comment: @AlexShwarc: Again, the problem is that there's no `#child` element in `ParentLayoutView.template`. So there's no region to render the child element into.

Comment: @AlexShwarc: That's why you got the "#child not in DOM" error.

Comment: I do not get that error. I inserted #child into parent template and nothing happened. Simply parent view replaces child view and it's all. There are window.alert in the code to pause execution and see how DOM is changing. And child is showed before parent, and after than parent replace its child. And second issue is that I want a child to be inserted into parent correctly (a added an appropriate id="child") and than parent should be inserted to DOM only once by one stroke. Instead it do to step by step with multiple insertions on DOM.

Comment: @AlexShwarc: What do you mean you don't get that error, that was a quote from your post! Anyway, we're just talking in circles. If you put up a jsfiddle of your code I will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Kevin, it works as expected. So I noticed my problem was a misunderstanding between region.el and region.selector attributes. I used
    childRegion: {
        el: "#child"
    }
because I did not provide a template. if no template provided to layout view only this option lets layout view to be rendered without error "missing el in DOM".

But if specify a template with #child inside and user region's selector option
    childRegion: "#child"
everything will be ok and DOM manipulation happens only one time, DOM tree is inserted correctly with all sub layouts.

So each layout view MUST have a template to work correctly with regions.